# Do Facebook developers get a cut of ads shown on their app page?

Tags: facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk, ads

My boss asked me an interesting question about if the developer gets a cut of the ads ran on their app page. I was unable to give him an answer. I tried to search for an answer and could not find one.

Comment: You can embed ads from any ad network here: https://developers.facebook.com/adproviders/ into your app on facebook
The ads Facebook themselves show in the Facebook part of the interface (i.e the right column) do not have a revenue sharing arrangement

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nope. You get no money whatsoever from just running your app.

The only way to make money, is to sell token to buy in-app stuff.

See this documentation for more information about in-app payments:
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/payments/

Comment: I think I knew that was coming. It would be a nice way to thank developers for traffic...

Comment: You can also host third party ads in your app for revenue - anyone on this list is allowed: https://developers.facebook.com/adproviders/

Answer (score 0):

More than 1000 apps are made on facebook on each day.The facebook apps are primarily made by different service level companies as a medium of promotion .They are in no mood or temptation to sell them .But if some people really want to sell the token id of the apps .

Comment: gIVE A CLEAR EXPLANATION ABOUT THE QUESTION